# Laravel eloquent get total of purchases by community name of suppliers

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I want to get all the number of purchases by the community name of the suppliers using laravel Eloquent. By the moment I have the next query which returns my desire result:

```
select count(suppliers.id) as total, communities.name as CommunityName , departments.name as Departament
from suppliers, purchases, communities, departments
where suppliers.id=purchases.supplier_id 
AND suppliers.community_id=communities.id
AND suppliers.department_id=departments.id
GROUP by suppliers.id, communities.name, departments.name
ORDER by total desc
```

Output:

```
#total #CommunityName #Department
1      Colpas         Lambayeque
3      Punas          Libertad
6      Punas          Lima
```

[image]

Using Eloquent I did it:

```
$purchases = Community::withCount(['suppliers' => function ($query) {
            $query->whereHas('purchases', function ($query) {
                //$query->where('','x');
            });
        }])->orderByDesc('suppliers_count')->get();
```

However I'm getting the three communities but number of suppliers_count is wrong.
My community model has a relation `hasMany` with the Supplier model:

`Community Model:`

```
public function suppliers() {
        return $this->hasMany(Supplier::class, 'community_id');
    }
```

And the supplier model has the next relation with `Purchase`
`Supplier Model`

```
public function purchases() {
        return $this->hasMany(Purchase::class, 'supplier_id');
    }
```

The next image has my db sheme:

[image]

And this is my ouput from the mysql raw query:

I hope were be careful with my question guys, I will appreciate your help thanks so much.

PD: My table 'communities' has a foreign key of 'department' table called 'department_id' of this way also I want to get the deparment name of the community but exists a relation inside the model Community with Department model.

Thanks

Comment: Supplier::withCount(['purchases'])->orderByDesc('purchases_count')->get(); Only tell me the number of purchases of each supplier.

Comment: Community::select(['communities.id','communities.name'])
                ->selectRaw("COUNT('purchases.*') as purchasesCount")
                ->join('suppliers','communities.id','suppliers.community_id')
                ->join('purchases','suppliers.id','purchases.supplier_id')
                ->orderBy('purchasesCount','desc')
                ->groupBy('communities.id')
                ->groupBy('communities.name')
                ->get(); worked for me. Any idea for Eloquent relations?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: I could do this report using joins, any idea for using relations?